# How to render animation using different text each time?

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I'm beginner in Blender and I don't even know if it is possible:
I have an animation which I need to render multiple times with only difference in name of person used. (Like *Hello, Mark* next render*Hello, Dan* and so on)...
I tried to use (to change the text): `bpy.data.objects["jmeno"].data.body = "Ahoj Dane"`
 in console ,
- there was no error, but nothing happened in 3d viewport. 
(btw. Jméno is in Czech name, ahoj is hello).
Thank You

Comment: Please upload your .blend

Comment: The command looks Ok to me.  Try selecting the text object (ie give it context) and type `C.object.data.body = "New Body"`  into the python console ( `C` is a py console shortcut for `bpy.context`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select = False

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Text']

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)

bpy.ops.font.delete(type='ALL')

bpy.ops.font.text_insert(text="Scripted text")
```